# Are these interpretation of same phrase/sentence acceptable?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

Imagine you see this headline:

> political hate campaign

Could that be used with these meanings:

1 - politicians that use hate in their campaign towards some other politicians

2 - people that carry out a hate campaign against politicians, as a sign of revolt at them.

Comment: You capitalized Hate Campaign, as if it is a known thing, was this intentional? Such as 'Black Lives Matter'  is a cultural movement, as 'black lives matter' is merely a phrase.

Comment: I didn't mean to capitalize, sorry! What i have in mind is the word 'hate' can lead the phrase to thse two alternative meaning

Comment: Newspaper headlines are not sentences, they are written to influence people to buy and/or to read them. There are many many examples of ambiguous (and often humorously ambiguous) newspaper headlines. Don't try to assign a specific meaning to a part of a newspaper headline; rather find a sentence in the full newspaper article and ask about the meaning of that sentence.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/296935/alternative-meaning-to-this-phrase-setence

Comment: It is, @kate Bunting. I really wanted to learn the clarification from some native English speaker

Comment: Well, now you have it from me and you have not reacted.

Answer (score 1):

Right, ok:

So, a hate campaign is a campaign of hate. It can be qualified: a political campaign of hate, AKA, a political hate campaign. That would mean an individual or organization or politician involved in spreading "political hate" towards some group. A nasty business, to be sure. The political refers to the field of endeavor (the political arena) and not the person necessarily, i.e., the politician.

**Please note**: A campaign can be carried out by a politician running for office (BrE: standing for office) or any other individual or group. There are a lot of **social media campaigns** in favor of this or that or against this or that.